# Is there a list of applicationError codes & descriptions for the Google AppEngine ApplicationException?

Tags: google-app-engine

Hello everyone and thanks up front for your time,

I am working on a java-based GAE web application and now and then I get ApiProxy.ApplicationExceptions.

In the current case they appear randomly and come with the applicationError 108 when I open a write channel to a blob using the (yes I know, still experimental) FileStore API. Although the API is still in an experimental state, I'd like to handle the thrown exception correctly. Thus my question:

**Where can I find a list of possible application errors including their descriptions?**

As of right now it is not possible for me to figure out where the problem resides since the thrown exception does not contain something like a message, hint or reason phrase but only the error ID 108:

```
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 108: 
    at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1495)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.doSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:240)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.access$000(ApiProxyImpl.java:66)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:183)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:180)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:180)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.TriggerFutureHook.makeSyncCall(TriggerFutureHook.java:154)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:107)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.makeSyncCall(FileServiceImpl.java:584)
    ... 65 more
```

Also, the corresponding javadoc is quite conservative with giving information: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/apphosting/api/ApiProxy.ApplicationException

Currently I bluntly cancel these requests with a 500, but since I am not sure what has happened I should probably do something else/more.

Thanksalot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best information I could get is from the Python source code :
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/files/file_service_pb.py

Comment: A note for others: Unfortunately, there are many possibilities for this error beyond the ones listed by David. For example, http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/runtime/apiproxy.py. Because of the way this proxy/stub system works, there's a range of possibilities, and you'll probably have to look at your stack trace to hunt down which set of error codes exactly are your concern.